# Data from XML to MSSQL using CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I'm having trouble extracting some data from a XML file to MSSQL DB using CROSS APPLY, here is what I have:

Note: I did read about how to post here but pardon me if I'm still wrong.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ZMPROD01>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
         <DOCNUM>0000003899888135</DOCNUM>
         <CREDAT>20220201</CREDAT>
         <CRETIM>152041</CRETIM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <ZPROD SEGMENT="1">
         <WERKS>8285</WERKS>
         <LGNUM>0</LGNUM>
         <AUFNR>000915229446</AUFNR>
         <LINENO>RM01PL01</LINENO>
         <CHARG>0006186588</CHARG>
         <START1>20220202</START1>
         <START2>211609</START2>
         <QTY>4166.000</QTY>
         <END1>20220202</END1>
         <END2>240000</END2>
         <MAKTX>579 FUS5 75ML ULTRA SENST GEL</MAKTX>
         <PLN_ORDER>6963701111</PLN_ORDER>
         <Z1PRODI SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000098920665</MATNR>
         </Z1PRODI>
         <Z1PRODI SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>000040</POSNR>
            <HRKFT>V010</HRKFT>
         </Z1PRODI>
         <Z1PRODI SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>000050</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000099396964</MATNR>
         </Z1PRODI>
      </ZPROD>
   </IDOC>
</ZMPROD01>
```

My SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO XMLTESTTABLE(PONo, ASP, LOTNo, EntryDate, StartDate, EndDate, GAS, PlannedQty, LineNum, SAPDesc, StartTime, EndTime)
SELECT
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('AUFNR').value('.', 'VARCHAR(9)'),
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('CHARG').value('.', 'VARCHAR(8)'),
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('PLN_ORDER').value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('START1').value('.', 'date'),
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('START1').value('.', 'date'),
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('END1').value('.', 'date'),
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('CHARG').value('.', 'VARCHAR(8)'),
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('QTY').value('.', 'VARCHAR(9)'),
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('LINENO').value('.', 'VARCHAR(1)'),
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('MAKTX').value('.', 'VARCHAR(9)'),
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('START2').value('.', 'time'),
   MY_XML.ZPROD.query('END2').value('.', 'time')
FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\PC_user\Documents\Idoc3899888135.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('ZMPROD01/ZPROD') AS MY_XML (ZPROD);
```

The result I get is (0 rows affected). I tried replacing ZMPROD01/ZPROD several times but different errors appeared, at some point complained about being unable to convert to date datatype.

On a separate note how, can I get data from EDI_DC40 as well? Not sure how the CROSS APPLY would look like to look for different places on the document.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Notable points:

- I adjusted the XPath expression in the `.nodes()` method.
- No need to use the `.query()` method.
- `text()` is added for performance reasons.
- Last  two data elements converted into `TIME` data type.
- As it was already mentioned, the `<END2>240000</END2>` is not a legit
  value for the `TIME` data type.

**SQL**

```
--INSERT INTO XMLTESTTABLE(PONo, ASP, LOTNo, EntryDate, StartDate, EndDate, GAS, PlannedQty, LineNum, SAPDesc, StartTime, EndTime)
SELECT ZPROD.value('(AUFNR/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(9)')
    , ZPROD.value('(CHARG/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)')
    , ZPROD.value('(PLN_ORDER/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)')
    , ZPROD.value('(START1/text())[1]', 'date')
    , ZPROD.value('(START1/text())[1]', 'date')
    , ZPROD.value('(END1/text())[1]', 'date')
    , ZPROD.value('(CHARG/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)')
    , ZPROD.value('(QTY/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(9)')
    , ZPROD.value('(LINENO/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(1)')
    , ZPROD.value('(MAKTX/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(9)')
    , TRY_CAST(STUFF(STUFF(ZPROD.value('(START2/text())[1]', 'CHAR(6)'),3,0,':'),6,0,':') AS TIME)
    , TRY_CAST(STUFF(STUFF(ZPROD.value('(END2/text())[1]', 'CHAR(6)'),3,0,':'),6,0,':') AS TIME)
FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\Temp\Idoc3899888135.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('/ZMPROD01/IDOC/ZPROD') AS MY_XML (ZPROD);
```

Comment: Almost worked, it's showing like this:
EntryDate 2022-02- and StartTime 21:16:

Comment: I changed the database datatype back to date and both appear fine now, only issue is that EndTime coming from END2 is NULL, for some reason didn't like that one.

Comment: `<END2>240000</END2>` It is not a legit value for the TIME data type.

Answer (score 0):

Your path seems wrong - what about:

```
CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('ZMPROD01/IDOC/ZPROD') AS MY_XML (ZPROD);
```

You seem to have forgotten the IDOC

And the data type is because you cannot convert the times to the data type time. Try starting with the select where everything is converted to varchar, then start changing the data tyoes, and you will find the errors

```
SELECT CAST('211609' AS TIME)
```

returns error

Comment: This is the error I get about converting to date:    
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: That is because sql server does not recognize the time format. You can add ":" between hours and minutes, and minutes and seconds, to make it recognize it, but still you will get an issue because the time "24:00:00" is not a time of day!
"  CAST(STUFF(STUFF(MY_XML.ZPROD.query('START2').value('.', 'varchar(10)'),3,0,':'),6,0,':') AS TIME) "

Comment: I changed everything related to date and time to varchar on the table and on the SQL query above and now works, only issue is that the date and time are plain numbers, not actually formatted properly.

I guess we can't sort that out?

Comment: You can use "stuff" to insert characters in a string, as I did above - but you still have to check for illegal values such as 240000